# LTSpice: How to convert netlist to .asc?

Tags: ltspice

I have LTSpice on macOS.

Is it possible to automatically convert a `.cir` netlist to `.asc` file?

In other words, I would like to obtain the schematic file from the netlist. How could I do it?
(I know that I can do the opposite, so from `.asc` to `.cir`)

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/511346/95619)?

Comment: yes, sorry. I read this thread and the answer to my question is basically no.