# Convert SPICE Model Netlist to Schematics

Tags: spice

Is there any software to convert SPICE Models to a schematics?

In other terms, I am looking for an alternatif of [SpiceVision PRO](https://www.concept.de/SpiceVision.html)

Comment: LTspice? (some extra chars)

Comment: LTSpice is for simulation purpose. My goal is to visualize a SPICE Model at basic element level

Comment: What does "visualize" even mean to you? A SPICE model is just a list of coefficients for equations...use a text editor.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I want to converter the text model into a graphical schematics it's more understandable. The SpiceVision do it very well. I am looking for an alternative

Comment: There are no "graphical schematics" under a SPICE **model**. Perhaps you are really talking about a SPICE **subcircuit**. In any event, recommendations for specific products are off-topic here.

Comment: Correct, I mean subcircuit

Comment: @Abderrezak I'd just write the software. I already did something like this to generate ASCII schematics. Many years ago, though. It does take some thought. You will want the ability to recognize patterns within graphs and the process is likely NP-complete as there will be more than one possible solution. So you'll also need a grading algorithm that will measure "entropy." But at least the input parsing is pretty easy.

Answer (score 3):

I am only aware of two alternatives to the commercial software you linked in your question.  There could be others, and if anyone comments with more suggestions I can edit the answer.

1.) [NetlistViewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netlistviewer/)

2.) [LTspice Schematic Builder](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=LTspice_Tools_and_Applications#How_to_convert_SPICE_Netlist_to_an_LTspice_schematic)

I have little to no experience using either of the above.  I've manually "decompiled" netlist to LTspice schematic a couple times, but it's very tedious and only useful for learning the process or honing your skillz with SPICE syntax.  Therefore, I generally don't recommend the manual process unless the netlist is only a few lines.

Comment: I just tried NetlistViewer with 3 netlists, but I couldn't open any of them, one of them being clean SPICE netlist -- it complained about unknown component `X...`, which is a subcircuit with many pins. A pity, but I suspect all of them will suffer, sooner or later, of the same shortcomings. And [these reasons](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/511352/95619) are somewhere in the top list. And if some manage to show something, it's because they are showing small subcircuits with known elements (gates, RLC, etc), and are able to make certain guesses. I doubt it works everywhere, though.