# is it possible to see the .subckt model schematically?

Tags: ltspice, spice

I've just imported the .subckt of L6562A in LTspice. I want to analyze the subcircuit operation. Is it possible to see the subcircuit in a schematic appearance or do I have to design it myself?

Comment: This question pops up every now and then, like [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/511346/95619) (possible duplicate?).

Comment: @V.V.T This is the only good approach, at least until modern AI programmers decide to apply their newer craft tools (which are quite sophisticated these days) to this problem (which they won't likely do.)

Comment: The reason a schematic is helpful is because it is far easier to read and understand, but the reason that a schematic is easier to read and understand is because some human was drawing it to convey meaning to another human. I would not trust an automated tool to do this. For example look at the output generated by https://sourceforge.net/projects/netlistviewer/. If you want a schematic, I'd say your far better off drawing your own schematics as V.V.T suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in LTspice, but there are tools for that which are not recommended because the schematics are not as clear as human-made ones. It's better to make my own one.